# Union Query -> Pick One When Duplicate Value in Jet

Tags: ms-access, union, jet, duplicates

I'm using Access to fill in details in a database across 3 offline computers. This means they all have a copy of the database, do a day of info filling, then get manually uploaded to a central database. Horrid, but it's the only option.

I have a pre-filled database, key identifiers etc are all determined previously; we are adding information to the blank fields for these entries. (Started with 3 key fields, added a few info fields). The user selects an entry and edits it rather than creating one. I then use a script which takes each table and unions the three databases into a table for each. The users do not duplicate work (meaning you don't have Jack working on entry A as well as Jill working on entry A).

My question: **How can I get my union query to select all entries, even the unfilled ones, but let the filled ones take precedence? (aka bypass the "duplicate entry" error by choosing the filled in entry instead of the two unfilled entries?)**

ex:

```
JOHN's DB            JACK's DB              JILL's DB      --->      MASTER DB
A: 1, 1, __          1, 1, __              1, 1, "Yes"              1, 1, "Yes"
B: 1, 2, "No"        1, 2, __              1, 2, __                 1, 2, "No"
C: 1, 3, __          1, 3, __              1, 3, "No"               1, 3, "No"
```

Completely terrible way to do this (Unioning offline tables, that is) but we have little other choice due to many other uncontrollable factors.

Comment: Why do you want the unfilled fields? What of the change is from "Yes" to null?

Comment: It can't be; it's literally empty. That field is used to determine if info has been entered; imagine it as a "Yes, I have filled in this entry". We exported some data from another source and are now filling in details which didn't exist before. I want the unfilled fields because they are used for selection; the user can only edit an entry which exists already and fill it in, they cannot create something that was never there. The unfilled fields need to be used the next day, and since I simply copy the master backend to the other users, the master backend must also have the remaining empties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
 SELECT Id, Max(Field) 
 FROM ( Select Id, Field FROM John
        Union All ...)
 GROUP BY Id
```

Comment: I'll try it in a couple hours and get back to you. Except, I would have to use UNION instead, would I not? Does the MAX() function select 1 of 3 identical entries (because filled-in entries from the previous days will all be max)? UNION (afaik) chooses entirely unique entries, so `1, 1, "Yes"` is returned as well aswith `1, 1, __`, which would still allow the MAX() to do its work, but would only select one of the `1, 2, "Yes" | 1, 2, "Yes"` entries because they are identical, eliminating the choice for MAX()

Comment: Max does select one entry. Union All is faster than Union. In your question, you say that there will only be one filled in answer per id.

Comment: One NEW answer filled per ID, but the other databases should know that "this entry has been done", and they know that by uploading the other finished entries and referencing it.

Comment: Got it working.. but not in VBA. If I `debug.print` the VBA command text and paste it into an Access Query, it works, but not via `.Execute`.

Comment: If you post the VBA to your question, someone may spot the problem.

Comment: It's a clusterf**. The connection/execution is fine (as I didn't change the code, only the `.Commandtext`), it's just something about that query it doesn't like. I'll post it up anyways.